# How to manipulate/access json received from autocomplete ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I'm working on a web application which was not developed by me and I have the following autocomplete code which works with an AJAXcall:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://lainz.softwebsrl.it/ajax/autocompletecibo",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            type : 'post',
            data:{
                valore: request.term,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

and below in the file I have:

```
<div class="div1" style="float: left">
    <strong>Cerca Prodotto</strong><br/><br/>

    <form class="form">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="tags" value="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="btnaggiungi" src="http://lainz.softwebsrl.it/img/carrello.jpg" alt="Aggiungi" id="add_newProduct"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to access the received JSON from PHP. PHP queries MySQL and in the end performs this:

```
$ris2 = array();
foreach($ris as $single) 
{
    $value = $single["cibo"];
    $category = $single["categoria"];
    $id = $single["id"];
    $ris2[] = array(
        "value" => $value,
        "id" => $id,
        "category" => $category
    );
}
$valuesJson = Zend_Json::encode($ris2);
echo $valuesJson;
```

Where in `$ris` contains the result of the query with `fetchAll()`. How can I access `value`, `id`, `category` when the AJAX terminates? Where are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 'data' value in a callback function, success.

```
 success: function (data) {
     response(data);
     console.log(data);
 }
```

If type of data value is object,

```
 console.log(typeof data, data.id, data.value);
```

If data is not expected value, check on a XHR response data of Chrome development networks tabs.